# How do I write the type of a KdTree member in a struct?

Tags: rust, kdtree

I'm trying to use the [kdtree crate](https://github.com/mrhooray/kdtree-rs) to explore function approximation from sampled points.

I have a struct which is supposed to have a `kdtree` member. The type of the [`KdTree`](https://docs.rs/kdtree/0.5.1/kdtree/kdtree/struct.KdTree.html) is generic and the third parameter gives me a headache:

```
pub struct KdTree<A, T, U: AsRef<[A]>> { /* fields omitted */ }
```

This is my attempt:

```
use kdtree;

pub struct Approximator {
    tree: kdtree::KdTree<f32, f32, AsRef<[f32]>>,
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::convert::AsRef<[f32]> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     tree: kdtree::KdTree<f32, f32, AsRef<[f32]>>,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::convert::AsRef<[f32]> + 'static)`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required by `kdtree::kdtree::KdTree`
```

How do I write it so it compiles? My `Approximator` will also have some runtime `dimension` depending on the n-arity of the function I try to approximate.

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec2f9ebd09d433c6d66060527da7c225, your question could be improved a lot. I have trouble to find the good crate

Comment: What **concrete** type are you using for `U`? If you show the code used to construct it, that will tell you what needs to go there.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thats the problem. I have not even the foggiest idea why it has 3 generic arguments in the first place. So I could not care less what it means. Coming from C++ I am tempted to think it is some way of the implementer to express, that he wants an array slice of ``A`` inside somehow. But as the rest of the API looks dynamic as far as ``dim`` is concerned, it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code I came up with the following interpretation on the types required to define kdtree:

```
// The definition is of the form: KdTree<A, T, U> it has 3 generic types:
// A = the type used for the partion space - it has to be a float type
// T = the attribute type - in this case its an integer usize
// U = the type used for the points in this case: [f32, f32, f32]
//
// U must be of the same type as type A as it needs to satisfy the 
// constrain AsRef<[A]> and it must match the number of dimensions 
// when calling new()
```

There are some code examples in this article, that I wrote: [KDTrees in Rust for Searching Spatial Data](https://medium.com/@Jayseabee/kdtrees-in-rust-for-searching-spatial-data-a10cdd3466d0)

Comment: When linking to a blog that is your own (or to which you have affiliation), you **must explicitly disclose that** or your post may be flagged as spam.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. When you paste the example code from the documentation

```rust
let a: ([f64; 2], usize) = ([0f64, 0f64], 0);
let b: ([f64; 2], usize) = ([1f64, 1f64], 1);
let c: ([f64; 2], usize) = ([2f64, 2f64], 2);
let d: ([f64; 2], usize) = ([3f64, 3f64], 3);

let dimensions = 2;
let mut kdtree = KdTree::new(dimensions);

kdtree.add(&a.0, a.1).unwrap();
kdtree.add(&b.0, b.1).unwrap();
kdtree.add(&c.0, c.1).unwrap();
kdtree.add(&d.0, d.1).unwrap();
```

you get that the type of `kdtree` is `kdtree::kdtree::KdTree<f64, usize, &[f64; 2]>`.